# Cannot connect InfluxDB2 by Laravel Http client

Tags: laravel, http, influxdb

Found that I cannot connect to local InfluxDB v2 via Laravel Http client:

```
    public function test(): mixed
    {
        /*
         * Works!
         * curl --location 'http://localhost:8086/api/v2' \
         * --header "Authorization: Token sbjyWZxcUgUMwywJ2X_AIxr4IqdrOViZP1f9INygGzGATW8Chhp1gXxZ_X-dMQAUY4QJLndS02_NeARrU42aWA=="
         */

        // Doesn't work!
        return Http::
            withToken('M1fzBAnjG26mVpdEkIkeq7ztEcA4SDp6w-HfN-sRU-oKnGoFc0Fncg1QzyGt6OQM7o3KMEgeA6fD3AVKgCejIw==')
            ->post('http://localhost:8086/api/v2');
        // Works!
//        return response(
//            shell_exec(sprintf("curl --location '%s/api/v2/signin' --header \"Authorization: Token %s\"", $this->baseUrl(), $this->getToken()))
//        );
    }
```

Guess, uncommented code duplicates curl which is 100% working.
But Laravel Http client cannot connect to http://localhost:8086:

> Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException: cURL error 7: Failed to
> connect to localhost port 8086 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to
> server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
> http://localhost:8086/api/v2 in file
> /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php
> on line 926

What's wrong - InfluxDB settings or my code with Laravel Http client?